# Unidirectional OneToMany Hibernate without an extra join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, join

The setup is this: My Application has many Events that could happen. An Event is just a few added fields and an EventCode that has some information. Basically Events is a join table itself with a few pieces of information added on.

I want to avoid creating a table of ApplicationId and EventId. Just does not seem needed

The error I am getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_157jxjblselu4urv8c0kqee6l:ApplicationEvent [applicationEvents_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ApplicationEvent [Application_id,applicationEvents_id])
```

Application (A lot removed but this is where the issue is)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Application {
    //Lots of other stuff
    private Set<ApplicationEvent> applicationEvents = new LinkedHashSet<ApplicationEvent>();

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="ApplicationEvent")
    public Set<ApplicationEvent> getApplicationEvents() {
        return applicationEvents;
    }

    public void setApplicationEvents(Set<ApplicationEvent> applicationEvents) {
        this.applicationEvents = applicationEvents;
    }
}
```

The Event

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ApplicationEvent {

    private Long id;
    private Long applicationId;
    private EventCode eventCode;
    private Boolean acknowledge;
    private int sequence;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public Long getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(Long applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EventCodeId")
    public EventCode getEventCode() {
        return eventCode;
    }

    public void setEventCode(EventCode eventCode) {
        this.eventCode = eventCode;
    }

    @Column
    public Boolean getAcknowledge() {
        return acknowledge;
    }

    public void setAcknowledge(Boolean acknowledge) {
        this.acknowledge = acknowledge;
    }

    @Column
    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

//Some overriden methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This mapping doesn't make sense: you're using the table ApplicationEvent as a join table between Application and ApplicationEvent.

Just remove `applicationId` (since this column is the one materializing the OneToMany association, i.e. the join column) from the `ApplicationEntity`, and use

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "applicationId")
```

Comment: That was a dumb mistake on my part thanks for the catch. I have since went a different route though that went against my problem statement. Application is needed on Events it appears.